# Add input fields to div container (javascript)

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

I want to add some html data to the end of a div container.
Currently, I do it with using innerHtml:

```
<script language="javascript">
var addid = 0;

function addInput(id){
    var docstyle = document.getElementById('addlist').style.display;
    if(docstyle == 'none')
        document.getElementById('addlist').style.display = '';

    addid++;

    var text = "<div id='additem_"+addid+"'><input type='text' size='100' value='' class='buckinput' name='items[]' style='padding:5px;' /> <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='addInput("+addid+")' id='addlink_"+addid+"'>add more</a></div>";

    document.getElementById('addlist').innerHTML += text;
}
</script>

<div id="addlist" class="alt1" style="padding:10px;">
    New list items are added to the bottom of the list.
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

The problem is that the value that was entered in the input fields is removed once another input field is added.
How can I add content without and keep the entered data?

PS: I do not use jquery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`innerHTML` changes reset form elements. Instead use `appendChild`. See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/5sWA2/

```
function addInput(id) {

    var addList = document.getElementById('addlist');
    var docstyle = addList.style.display;
    if (docstyle == 'none') addList.style.display = '';

    addid++;

    var text = document.createElement('div');
    text.id = 'additem_' + addid;
    text.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='' class='buckinput' name='items[]' style='padding:5px;' /> <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='addInput(" + addid + ")' id='addlink_" + addid + "'>add more</a>";

    addList.appendChild(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/appendChild

So something like

```
document.getElementById('addlist').appendChild(text);
```