# New input in javascript appears and dissappears on click

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, input

Using Javascript I would like to create a new input text with the click of a button. This is my code:

```
<section id="poststarring">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 2;
        function newactor(){
           document.getElementById("actorinput").innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="starring"' + counter + ' value="actor" class="starring"> <span>as</span> <input type="text" name="as"' + counter + ' value="character" class="character">';
           counter += 1; 
           return false;
        }
    </script>
    <section id="actorinput">
        <input type="text" name="starring1" value="actor" class="starring"> <span>as</span> <input type="text" name="as1" value="character" class="character">
    </section>
    <button onclick="newactor()">Add another actor</button>
</section>
```

This code is found withing a larger form that works as it should, and above it a section of php.

When i click the button the new input appears for a second and dissappears right away. I have tried several things already: I have foound different javascript codes, and I have changed the position of the javascript code to the head. The two possible soulutions I have found researching this problem - adding return false to the function, and making sure the buttons are  not  have not helped me so far.

Comment: please follow this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9455066/add-input-fields-to-div-container-javascript

Comment: Do you really dump jQuery in favor of Javascript ? Weired ! huh  ?

Comment: The way the code is written, it should not cause the button to disappear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<button>` inside a form submits the form, that's why the element disappears right away, the page reloads.

You're returning false from the function, but you probably wanted to do

```
<button onclick="return newactor()">Add another actor</button>
```

as you have to return the `false` back the handler as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using appendChild to add the new elements since innerHTML is going to wipe away the values and any events that may be attached.

```js
        var counter = 2;
        function newactor(){
           var div = document.createElement("div");
           div.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="starring"' + counter + ' value="actor" class="starring"> <span>as</span> <input type="text" name="as"' + counter + ' value="character" class="character">';
          document.getElementById("actorinput").appendChild(div);
           counter += 1; 
           return false;
        }
```

```html
<section id="poststarring">
    <section id="actorinput">
        <input type="text" name="starring1" value="actor" class="starring"> <span>as</span> <input type="text" name="as1" value="character" class="character">
    </section>
    <button onclick="newactor()">Add another actor</button>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved a problem that I didn't even knew I had yet

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
document.getElementById("actorinput").appendChild( '<input type="text" name="starring"' + counter + ' value="actor" class="starring"> <span>as</span> <input type="text" name="as"' + counter + ' value="character" class="character">');
```